# How to write math equation with auto numbers

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I can write a math equation as below:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
2x+y-3=0 .... (1) \\
3x-5y+7=0 .... (2)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

In this example, the equation number is added manually, is it possible to generate automatically? then if I have multiple equations, it can be numbered automatically.

Comment: Use $$2x+y-3 \tag {1} $$

Comment: If you're asking how to auto-number *here*, on Math.SE using MathJax, then (I think) the answer is: you can't. However, in a true $\TeX$ word processor (TeXShop, etc), you would get numbering for free. (By the way, as @Salahamam_Fatima notes, you should use `\tag{}` for your equation numbers, as in `\tag{1}`, `\tag{2}`, etc. The parenthesized numbers will appear aligned at the far right; no need for separating dots.)

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima \tag sounds like tag the whole equation array as one number, if I add it to two equation one by one, it will report "multiple tag" error.

Comment: @lucky1928: It seems a little hacky, but you can get `tag` to work inside of `cases`, if you wrap the equations in an additional `align`. For instance, `$$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}2x+\phantom{5}y-3&=0\tag{1}\\ 3x-5y+7&=0 \tag{2}\end{align}\end{cases}$$` yields $$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
2x+\phantom{5}y-3&=0\tag{1} \\
3x-5y+7&=0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$ (But now, the brace is a bit too far to the left. Hmmm ...)

Comment: In LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is what is used here) there are control sequences that will cause these to be generated by the software. That way if you have $50$ of them and you want to insert another after the $20\text{th}$ one, you don't have to manually re-number the ones that come after that. But sometimes you have to run LaTeX twice on the same file to get this result. That's because the first time it runs, it stores information in an auxiliary file and then uses that the second time it runs.

Comment: It appears that the MathJax folks added an autonumber feature in v.2.0.  See the new features write-up [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html), and scroll down to the section on Automatic Equation Numbering (about 15% down the page).  They note that the feature is turned off by default.

Comment: @hardmath: if this is turned on for this site then will the numbering be for entire page or for each post on  a page (this is what we need)? Perhaps this can be experimentally tested by moderators.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a note on semantics of displayed math: A brace signifies a _single logical equation_ that happens to consist of two or more equations. Either the brace should get one single number, or--if each equation deserves its own number--the brace should go. ;) (Separately, I myself would lean against auto-numbering in web content, because cutting-and-pasting MathJaX source might break cross references. That, however, is more a matter of opinion than the issue with braces and multiple numbers.)

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is what is used here) there are control sequences that will cause these to be generated by the software. That way if you have $50$ of them and you want to insert another after the $20\text{th}$ one, you don't have to manually re-number the ones that come after that. But sometimes you have to run LaTeX twice on the same file to get this result. That's because the first time it runs, it stores information in an auxiliary file and then uses that the second time it runs.

Comment: I think TeXworks gives one the option to delete auxiliary files. I think also one can do that through the operating system without causing any problems for TeXworks. Of course that doesn't help Mr. Lucky here.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks : The relevance of your comment escapes me. What would be done differently if an auxiliary file were deleted, in a way that is relevant to what we're talking about here?

Comment: It's relevant only because you mentioned LaTeX "as opposed to MathJax," Mr. Hardy. Otherwise I wouldn't even have thought about auxiliary files at all.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks : Your comments relevance still escapes me. Is deleting the auxiliary file something that you would do for some purpose? What would that be?

Comment: After getting an error, if I fix the error in the source file but don't delete the aux files compilation might still fail. I thought I mentioned I brought this up only because you mentioned LaTeX.

Comment: You did say that you brought up deletion of aux files only because I mentioned MathJax. But only in your most recent comment did you mention some reason for deleting the aux file.

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry for dragging us down this pointless and tiresome tangent.

Answer (score 2):

mathjax now supports auto numbering line, but turn off by default.

### Usage

```
<script>
    window.MathJax = {
        tex: {
            tags: "ams"
        }
    };
</script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    id="MathJax-script"
    async
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
></script>
```

Now all equations will have auto numbering tag.

Related doc:

[Automatic Equation Numbering](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/eqnumbers.html)